# Python - Can't run a timer in Tornado without blocking the clients from connecting to the server

Tags: python, timer, tornado, countdown

Not very experienced in Tornado so sorry if it sounds like a newbie question.

I am building a card game with the clients using standard html/js code and tornado on the server. Everything is working fine however I need to implement a countdown on the server where after a certain amount of time a certain code runs. I am using the following python code and calling it from the tornado after a request has been made

```
import time

class StartTimer(object):

    timerSeconds = 0

    def __init__(self):

        print "start timer initiated"
    def initiateTime(self, countDownSeconds):
        self.timerSeconds = countDownSeconds

        while self.timerSeconds >= 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            print self.timerSeconds
            self.timerSeconds -=1

            if self.timerSeconds == 0:
                #countdown finishes
                print "timer finished run the code"


    def getTimer(self):

        return self.timerSeconds
```

The countdown works fine however I have two issues firstly, while the timer is counting down the server blocks any other connection and puts them in the queue and runs the code after the timer has finished secondly, I need the getTimer function to work so a new client coming in knows how much time has left (basically getting the timerSeconds value). I can possibly get away with the timer not showing to the users however the fact that the code is blocked is definitely not good.

Please help

Comment: Not a complete answer (sorry, I don't know Tornado), but: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout appears to be how timers are done.  Your code doesn't work because `time.sleep()` simply blocks the whole thread for one second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`time.sleep()` will block, use `add_timeout()` instead
check [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html?highlight=time#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout)

Edit: sorry, it has been answered by  @Armin Rigo

here is [an example](https://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/ae9b7527bf3d8948/ceeb64cfd39b0c1f?lnk=gst&q=how%20to%20make%20a%20periodic%20post%20after%20X%20seconds#ceeb64cfd39b0c1f):

```
import time
import tornado.ioloop


def delayed_print(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        ioloop.stop()
    else:
        print s[0]
        ioloop.add_timeout(time.time() + 1, lambda:delayed_print(s[1:]))

ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop()
delayed_print('hello world')
ioloop.start()
```

Comment: I have tried this with no luck. Maybe its because Im not sure how/where to include it also I need the timer to start as a result of a client action rather than automatically. I included the add_timeout like this:if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    app = Application()
    

    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop(500, time.run()) Is this right? Thanks a lot for the responses

Comment: look here https://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/363189360bea2dca

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and sorry for the delay. I have been trying everything to get this to work. I tried threading in python which works in the background however, When I need to send the message that the timer is up to the client I get a cannot write() after finish() exception so the application breaks. I just tried your sample and it works however it blocks the server completely and also I cant see a way that I can initiate it in the middle of the application rather than at the beginning. I had never thought making a simple timer is going to cost me this much time and money.

Comment: how this is blocking your server? `time.sleep()` will block the cpu, but if you use the tornado's `ioloop.add_timeout()` will behave the same thing when you're in a single machine! synchronous is about multi request! so the difference will be : if A and B and C are requesting, then B and C will not wait for A to complete untill getting their job.

Comment: this can also help?
http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html?highlight=periodiccallback#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback

Answer (score 1):

[IOLoop.call_later](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.call_later) will be more convenient since Tornado 4.0. for the relative case since it does not require a timedelta object.